# What is the value of the exchange field in the 3d ferromagnets ($\rm Ni, Fe, Co$)?

Tags: material-science, ferromagnetism, data, exchange-interaction

I have been trying to find the values of the exchange field for Ni, Co and Fe. This website mentions, "Exchange forces are very large, equivalent to a field on the order of 1000 Tesla" https://cse.umn.edu/irm/2-classes-magnetic-materials.

I can't find any papers of textbooks that give more specific values (other than for very niche materials). Any advice on where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess that's because the description in terms of the exchange field is just an approximation that does not accurately describe the complex many-body system of real materials, so you can just give an estimate for the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Exchange is not usually discussed in terms of the effective magnetic field strength. Search for "exchange stiffness" (in pJ/m usually) or "exchange energy" in eV.

From there, you can calculate the effective magnetic field using the Zeeman energy (energy of a magnetic dipole in a magnetic field).

The reason the values are not very accurate is because they strongly vary with temperature, crystal direction, crystal phase, material purity, material nanostructure and because the exchange stiffness is hard to measure directly.